# Is there any way to enumerate over a collection passed from SilverLight to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Right now it looks like one should be aware of available keys to access the values in the passed collection. Sometimes this is very inconvenient, for example when SilverLight constructs the object on the fly?

So far I couldn't find any direct work around.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org) to iterate (and a lot more things) over the values you get.

You can use `_.keys(myvar)` to get the keys of that object.

Comment: The main problem of the collection passed from SilverLight is that  for some reason it is not enumerable (you can't do: for ... in ... and other kind of loops on it). Do you still think that UnderscoreJS might help me?

Comment: What type of data is returned exactly? I think you should give it a try as you won't spend more than 5 minutes in it.